# Deshacerse de la lista en celdas de una dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, pandas, dataframe

Tengo una dataframe y me gustaria saber si el contenido en las celdas es una lista o no y deshacerme de ello si es el caso:

```
>>>data3[data3.QType=='Multiple Choice'].iloc[16:19,3:13]
    Questions   Answers     Section     QType   Theme   Topics  Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3
17  What is you preference of room/suites with bal...   ['Preferred', 'Not preferred']  Consumer Intentions     Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['prefer', 'room', 'suit', 'balconi']   Preferred   Not preferred   NaN     NaN
18  How do you want your guestroom to look like?    ['Contemporary style guestrooms', ['18lKwM8N2E...   Consumer Intentions     Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['want', 'guestroom', 'look', 'like']   Contemporary style guestrooms   ['18lKwM8N2EuQujkFj81pcSrt5bjy9wppKC8mjYQZp0L0...   Traditional style guestrooms    ['1OL5AUAqisiQBDrkNM0OQ0_NcHxmisM0y8I6OJpRcSdI...
19  How do you want to know about our recent offer...   ['Personalized emails', 'Text messages', 'Web ...   Media Consumption   Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['want', 'know', 'recent', 'offer']     Personalized emails     Text messages   Web Blogs   Paper advertisements
```

Intenté:

```
import numpy as np
import ast

def get_rid_of_images(cell):
    try:
        question = ast.literal_eval(cell)
        question_type = type(question)
        if question_type == list:
            return None
        else: return cell
    except SyntaxError:
        return cell
    except ValueError:
        return cell
```

import ast

```
data3 = data2.copy()
columns = [x for x in data3.iloc[:,9:].columns]
for column in columns:
    data3.loc[data3.QType=='Multiple Choice',column].iloc[:20,3:25] = data3[data3.QType=='Multiple Choice'].apply(get_rid_of_images)
```

Pero no cambia nada

Al menos para ver si funciona, pero el mensaje que confirmaría que nunca aparece.

## Actualizacion

Intenté la respuesta de Pablo Prieto

```
import ast 

def remove_list(cell):
    try:
        value = ast.literal_eval(cell)
        if type(value) == list:
            return None
        else:
            return cell
    except SyntaxError:
        return cell
    except ValueError:
        return cell

columns = [x for x in data3.iloc[:,9:].columns]
data3[columns] = data3[columns].applymap(remove_list)
```

El resultado es

```
    Section     QType   Theme   Topics  Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4     Answer5
17  Consumer Intentions     Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['prefer', 'room', 'suit', 'balconi']   Preferred   Not preferred   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
18  Consumer Intentions     Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['want', 'guestroom', 'look', 'like']   Contemporary style guestrooms   None    Traditional style guestrooms    None    Classical style guestrooms  None
19  Media Consumption   Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['want', 'know', 'recent', 'offer']     Personalized emails     Text messages   Web Blogs   Paper advertisements    Video advertisements    Advertisements on social media
```

Sin embargo, ¿sabría usted, en la función y cuando hay listas, cómo mover las respuestas que están en el lado derecho de las listas? Para obtener una cosa como:

```
Section     QType   Theme   Topics  Answer0     Answer1     Answer2     Answer3     Answer4     Answer5
17  Consumer Intentions     Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['prefer', 'room', 'suit', 'balconi']   Preferred   Not preferred   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
18  Consumer Intentions     Multiple Choice     Hotel ABC   ['want', 'guestroom', 'look', 'like']   Contemporary style guestrooms   Traditional style guestrooms    Classical style guestrooms  None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con algo como esto:

```py
import pandas as pd
x = [[[1, 2, 3], 'hello'], [[5, 6, 7], 'adios']]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(x)
```

Esto genera este dataframe:

```
           0      1
0  [1, 2, 3]  hello
1  [5, 6, 7]  adios
```

Si aplicas esto:

```py
def remove_list(cell):
    if type(cell) == list:
        return None
    else:
        return cell
        
df = df.applymap(remove_list)

# O mediante un lambda
df = df.applymap(lambda x: None if type(x) is list else x)
```

Se transforma en:

```py
      0      1
0  None  hello
1  None  adios
```

El método applymap te permite operar sobre cada celda de tu Data Frame:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html

Evita usar `except SyntaxError`. No tiene sentido manejar un error de sintaxis como: `else: return cell`

Comment: ¡Gracias por su respuesta! Sin embargo, tengo que eliminar sólo unas pocas columnas de la lista que comienza con `Answer` en singular con los números después de ella (`Answers` es una lista dondé dejaré todas las respuestas y tengo que dejarlo  en paz...) Así que probé su función en `data3.loc[:,column].applymap(remove_list)` pero me devuelve: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'`